# How to i make a user when register on my asp.net website, to register also for a paypal account and return back to my website?

Tags: paypal

How to i make a user when register on my asp.net website, to register also for a paypal accountn while sign in into the website and return back to my website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Adaptive Accounts API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/) to tie the PayPal account creation process into your app.

If you're working with PHP my [class library](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) will make this very simple for you.  You would just open up the CreateAccount.php template file and fill it out accordingly to suit your needs.  Most likely you'd be passing form POST or SESSION data to it, so you could just drop those values into the provided parameters that are already setup for you in the template.